# does anyone knows how to easily determine the composition of the swing component on Frame? without using netbeans or windows builder

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I mean, I want to do it manually but to determine the location I want to know what there is an alternative way

For example program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class testLotus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame gui= new JFrame();
        JLabel h1 = new JLabel("Some text");
        JTextField text = new JTextField(15);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        h1.setBounds(180,50,120,20); //this is it
        text.setBounds(180,90,120,20); // and this

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(h1);
        panel.add(text);

        gui.getContentPane().add(panel);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(800,600 );
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explane what is for you "composition of swing component"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the location of your components by traversing them and printing all the properties you are interested in. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestLotus {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TestLotus().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel h1 = new JLabel("Some text");
        JTextField text = new JTextField(15);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        h1.setBounds(180,50,120,20); //this is it
        text.setBounds(180,90,120,20); // and this

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(h1);
        panel.add(text);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        printComponents(frame, "");
    }

    private void printComponents(Container container, String indent) {
        for (Component component : container.getComponents()) {
            System.out.println(indent + "component.getClass().getName(): " 
                               + component.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println(indent + "component.getBounds(): " 
                               + component.getBounds());

            if (component instanceof Container) {
                printComponents((Container) component, indent + "    ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your output would look something like this:

```
component.getClass().getName(): javax.swing.JRootPane
component.getBounds(): java.awt.Rectangle[x=9,y=38,width=782,height=553]
    component.getClass().getName(): javax.swing.JPanel
    component.getBounds(): java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=782,height=553]
    component.getClass().getName(): javax.swing.JLayeredPane
    component.getBounds(): java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=782,height=553]
        component.getClass().getName(): javax.swing.JPanel
        component.getBounds(): java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=782,height=553]
            component.getClass().getName(): javax.swing.JPanel
            component.getBounds(): java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=782,height=553]
                component.getClass().getName(): javax.swing.JLabel
                component.getBounds(): java.awt.Rectangle[x=180,y=50,width=120,height=20]
                component.getClass().getName(): javax.swing.JTextField
                component.getBounds(): java.awt.Rectangle[x=180,y=90,width=120,height=20]
```

Comment: after JFrame.pack and/or JFrame.setVisible(true)

Comment: Yes, you want the layout to be done; otherwise the output would be far less interesting. (Since the label and the text field are positioned explicitly and the layout of the panel is `null`, the coordinates for these components are visible anyway.) In the example above, the call to `printComponents(frame, "");` is made after the frame has been made visible.

Comment: hmmm back to NullLayout, this is (quite sure) only one reason why your answers aren't upvoted here, and also in my case

Comment: I used the code from the OP, so it was not my decision. I prefer to use layout managers whenever possible and in this case I thought the use of a `null` layout was not important for the question (as far as I have understood it at least). It is nice to get votes, but my main goal is to help people resolve a programming issue. Please feel free to save your upvotes for other answers... :-)

Comment: 1. I used the code from the OP - how many times today and yesterday seems like as the similair ... :-) 2. [good idea as you can see in 3rd. line](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)